# Handling URLs with a REST API?

Tags: php, api, url

i know that when creating a php website i can use something like: index.php?id=2 and the index.php can fetch the id with: $_GET['id']. I want to create an api for one of my websies and i see different examples.

Twitter:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?count=2&since_id=14927799
```

So, i create a folder "1.1" and a folder "statuses" on my FTP-Server with the file mentions_timeline.json which understands $_GET['count'] etc. ?

Other APIs look like this:

```
https://quote.fm/api/recommendation/delete
```

And i can delete a recommendation with:

```
https://quote.fm/api/recommendation/delete/?id=1 or
https://quote.fm/api/recommendation/delete/1
```

Usually with websites i can create such url structure to make it work using mod_rewrite. As i understand here i create different urls for different sections:

```
https://xyz.com/api/user/get/1
https://xyz.com/api/user/delete/1
```

So i create a folder user with the subfolders delete and get on the FTP-Server, each having a index.php file? How does my script then know that /1 is id=1?

Does somebody understand me? I have difficulties to understand how my script can translate the url structure into necessary pieces of data that are coming from the app.

Thanks!

Comment: You're either looking for *"pretty URLs"* (google it) or a full *router* (read this: https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router#what-urls-are-and-how-to-set-up-routing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just copy this chapter from [the readme of my router implementation](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router#what-urls-are-and-how-to-set-up-routing) here:

> ### What URLs are and how to set up routing
>
> A URL is simply a string consisting of several parts:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/foo?bar=baz
>   |         |       |    |
>   |         |       |    +- query
>   |         |       +- path
>   |         +- host
>   +- scheme
> ```
>
> A URL may additionally have authentication information, a port and a
>   fragment, but we'll try to keep it simple here. Kunststube\Router
>   exclusively deals with the path. The scheme and query typically have
>   no influence on routing and the host is typically handled by the web
>   server.
>
> Assuming a typical setup using an Apache web server, Apache usually
>   does the "routing" for you. It receives an HTTP request looking
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> GET /foo/bar/baz?some=parameters HTTP/1.1
> ```
>
> The web server is now free to respond to this request in any way it
>   chooses. The default thing most web servers do is to map the URL's
>   path to files on the hard disk. The web server will first figure out
>   what the appropriate *DocumentRoot* is, i.e. the folder on disk that
>   has been configured as "the public web folder". Let's assume the
>   DocumentRoot is `/var/www`. It will then concatenate the request path
>   to that root, resulting in `/var/www/foo/bar/baz`. It will then try to
>   figure out if that file exists on disk and serve it up as response. If
>   the requested file ends with `.php` or Apache is otherwise configured
>   to treat the file as PHP file, it will first run the file through the
>   PHP interpreter before returning its output.
>
> To use our own custom routing using a PHP router, we need to intercept
>   the process of Apache looking up the file to serve on disk. This can
>   be done in the Apache configuration files; but if you have access to
>   these files I'm assuming you know what you're doing and won't go into
>   the specific details of the best setup there. Instead I'll cover the
>   typical case where you cannot or don't want to edit the core Apache
>   configuration files and instead resort to `.htaccess` files. When
>   Apache traverses the directory structure on the disk to find the
>   correct file to serve, it checks in each directory whether a file
>   called `.htaccess` is placed in it. If it finds one, it will execute
>   and/or incorporate the rules defined within it into the file lookup
>   process, then continue on to the next deeper directory in the path.
>
> What you want to achieve is to make Apache "find" and execute one
>   particular PHP file for any and all requests and make the original URL
>   available to that PHP file so it can do its own routing. The easiest,
>   dirtiest way to do this is a simple `RewriteRule`:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=/$1 [QSA,L] 
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> Lets assume you put this into the file `/var/www/.htaccess`. When
>   Apache starts its file lookup in that directory, it will parse these
>   rewrite rules. The "internal state" of the path Apache is looking for
>   at this point is `foo/bar/baz`. The regular expression `^(.*)$` of the
>   `RewriteRule` will match that path (the expression basically says
>   "match anything"), and the rule will rewrite the path to
>   `index.php?url=/foo/bar/baz`. The original `some=parameters` is then
>   appended again to that path/URL (due to the `QSA` flag). Apache will
>   then continue looking for the now rewritten path `index.php`. So just
>   put your code into `/var/www/index.php` and Apache will launch the PHP
>   interpreter for it. PHP will be passed the URL query part
>   `?url=/foo/bar/baz&some=parameters`, which in PHP can be accessed as
>   `$_GET['url']` and `$_GET['some']`. So the complete setup looks like
>   this:
>
> #### Basic setup
>
> File/folder structure
>
> ```
> /var
>     /www
>         .htaccess
>         index.php
>         /Kunststube
>             /Router
>                 Router.php
>                 ...
> ```
>
> .htaccess
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=/$1 [QSA,L] 
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> index.php
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> require_once 'Kunststube/Router/Router.php';
>
> $r = new Kunststube\Router\Router;
> $r->add('/foo');
> ...
> $r->route($_GET['url']);
> ```
>
> And that's all there is to it. A basic rewrite rule that redirects
>   every request to the same PHP file and appends the original URL as
>   query parameter, which is then used to invoke the routing process.
>
> #### Caveats and tweaks
>
> One important caveat to the above setup is that your URL cannot
>   contain a query parameter called `url`, since the original query
>   parameters are added back onto the rewritten URL. The URL
>   `/foo/bar?url=baz` would be rewritten to:
>
> ```
> index.php?url=/foo/bar&url=baz
> ```
>
> The second `url` parameter will replace the first. If you need to use
>   the query parameter `url` in your application, choose a different
>   parameter name for your rewrite rule.
>
> Secondly, note that the Kunststube\Router expects the URL passed to
>   `route()` to start with a `/`. You can add that slash during the
>   rewriting process as shown above, or in PHP; just make sure it's
>   there.
>
> Third, you usually also have files you do not want to route through
>   PHP, for example CSS and image files. You'll want those to be served
>   by Apache directly. A good setup for this is as such:
>
> ```
> /var
>     /Kunststube
>         /Router
>             ...
>     /MyApp
>         MyScript.php
>         ...
>     /www
>         .htaccess
>         index.php
>         /css
>             style.css
>             ...
>         /img
>             kitten.jpg
>             ...
> ```
>
> Take all the actual PHP files out of the public web root directory,
>   only leave public asset files and a minimal `index.php` file in there.
>   Adjust your RewriteRule to look like this:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=/$1 [QSA,L] 
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> The `RewriteCond` makes sure the `RewriteRule` only applies if the
>   requested file does not physically exist (`!-f`). That means requests
>   for the URL `css/style.css` will pass through as is, since the file
>   does actually exist and Apache can serve it directly. Any requests for
>   "imaginary" files that do not physically exist will go into
>   `index.php` and can be routed there. Inside `index.php`, make sure to
>   use the correct path to the router:
>
> ```
> require_once '../Kunststube/Router/Router.php';
> ```
>
> In fact, it's better practice to define your routes elsewhere entirely
>   and to use autoloaders to load required files, but this is outside the
>   scope of this document.